# Recur every x weeks

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, recurring

I'm developing a WPF application which uses ORM (EntityFramework). The application allows the user to plan certain tasks. These tasks could recur every x weeks. For example: Maintenance Google.com every 2 weeks (starting on monday).

The way I stored this is as followed. I've got a Task object with a field named 'StartDate' which is the date on which the task is first started. I've also made a field named 'Recur' (I know names could be better). The 'Recur' field holds the amount of weeks a certain task should recur. So in my example above it holds the number 2, since the maintenance on Google.com has to be done every 2 weeks.

Now comes the situation I'm facing; I want the user to be able to retrieve ALL tasks in a certain weeknumber. For example: Retrieve all tasks in week 42 of 2013. If I made a task which recurs every week, this means that when I want to retrieve all tasks of week 42 this task has to show up. It also has to show up when I retrieve all tasks for week 44, 46, 48, etc.

How am I able to determine whether a task falls in a specific weeknumber and select it? I've been trying the following:

```
context.Werk.Include("Debiteur").Where(o => o.Recur >= EntityFunctions.DiffDays(o.StartDate, today) / 7
                                                                && EntityFunctions.DiffDays(o.StartDate, today) / 7 % o.Recur == 0).ToList();
```

Basically what I tried to do is check if the amount of 'recur' weeks is equal or larger than the amount of date it differs between the startdate and today. I also checked if the amount of weeks it differs from the startdate and today is disivible by the 'recur' field.

Comment: You should keep the Recur time in a TimeSpan object.

Comment: Could you clarify why? Plus this doesn't really solve the issue right? Maybe its more tidy

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a specific answer as  woukd need more context (like how many items are there, is there already a class that handles the "Werk" (I'm Dutch ;-)). Is the collection already filtered that ont he the current "debiteur" is in the collection"). But I can point you in the right direction.

Create a work class like this:

```
public class Werk
{
    public bool IsRecurrungThisWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        // This can be implemented by yourself
    }

    public DateTime StartsFrom { get; set; }
    public int Recur { get;  set; }
    public int Debiteur { get; set; }
}
```

And do a simple Where:

```
IEnumerable<Werk> list = GetWerkObjects();
var aDateOfTheWeek = new DateTime();
var werkRecurringThisWeek = list.Where(w => w.IsRecurrungThisWeek(aDateOfTheWeek));
```

Comment: Changing from `Queryable.Where<T>` to `Enumerable.Where<T>` is quite a difference...

Comment: @ta.speot.is You are right. This solution depends on the context. I prefer it when the the number of records is not very high, if the Ienumarable can be cached for the next request or if you already have a lot of logic in existing classes (like calculation for weeknumbers). In other scenario's you might want a different solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. In theory the amount of 'Werk' objects could be infinite. In practice the amount would stay under 50 I think.
@AlexSiepman : There is a Werk class, but this is my EF object (ORM). And no, the collection isn't filtered.